# #pragma mark defining - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf),

> The Swift compiler does not include a preprocessor. Instead, it takes
>   advantage of compile-time attributes, build configurations, and
>   language features to accomplish the same functionality. For this
>   reason, preprocessor directives are not imported in Swift.

***So how could be use this great feature(#Pragma mark -) in Swift*** ?

Comment: // MARK:, // TODO: and // FIXME